# How can I put Json data to the UITableView using Swift 4?

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, swift4

I have this here structured:

```
struct Excercise: Codable {
    let excerciseID: String
    let excerciseName: String
    let description: String
    let intensity: Int
}
```

Then, that's the var:

```
var excercistList = [Excercise]()
```

And the cellforrowat:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ExcerciseCell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.excercistList[indexPath.row].excerciseName
    return cell
}
```

That's the URLSession:

```
 URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
                        guard let data = data else{return}

   do {
         let excerciseList = try JSONDecoder().decode(Excercise.self, from: data)
         print(excerciseList.excerciseName)
      } catch let jsonErr {
           print("Error", jsonErr)
      }
  }.resume()
```

I get the right results on the print, but nothing on the table.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does the array fills with the data that you want? `print(excerciseList.excerciseName)` <- This should not print anything cause you are not indicating the index, first check number of items and please show `numberOfRowsInSection` method.

Comment: You need a reloadData in your table after fill the array.

Comment: Did you call ```tableView.reloadData()``` after you got the array?

Comment: reloadData can help you.

Answer (score 1):

first of all you have to populate your `dataSource` which is `var excercistList = [Excercise]()`. After that you have to reload `tableView`.

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
                        guard let data = data else{return}

   do {
         let excerciseListFromDecoder = try JSONDecoder().decode(Excercise.self, from: data)
        self.excercistList =  excerciseListFromDecoder
        self.tableView.reloadData()
      } catch let jsonErr {
           print("Error", jsonErr)
      }
  }.resume()
```

---

You have to be sure that you have set correctly

```
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
```

and the `numberOfRowsInSection`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.excercistList.count
    }
```